# Make javascript regex case insensitive

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to filter some divs by text. It works, but its case sensitive no matter i parameter. Any ideas why?

```
$('#acc_search_item input').on('keyup', function(){
        var text = $(this).val();
        console.log(text);
        $('.item').hide();
        $('.item').filter(function(){ return $(this).find('.iname').text().match("^.*"+text+".*","gi")}).show();
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make it a regular expression:

```
match(new RegExp("^.*"+text+".*","gi"))
```